# Localizable file isn't working on device

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, localizable.strings

I've checked all the answers, tries to save them in TextWrangler as UTF-16, remove them and re-add to project, checked for duplicate files in other frameworks that i'm using, but nothing works.

2 xibs got localized but others, I just see the strings instead of the translation of the string itself.

[image]

[image]

---

Sorry, this is how I use the localization:

```
self.hkRoutineTitle.text = NSLocalizedString(@"HKRoutineTitle", nil);
[self.buttonChooseManagers setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"HKRoutineChooseMangersButton", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.buttonChooseParticipants setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"HKRoutineChooseParticipantsButton", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.buttonSubjectsToAttend setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"HKRoutineSubjectsToAttendButton", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.buttonCancel setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"HKRoutineCancelButton", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.buttonDone setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"HKRoutineDoneButton", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.catBtn setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"HKRoutineChooseCategoriesButton", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.hazBtn setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"HKRoutineChooseHazard", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.remark.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"HKRoutineNotesPlaceholder", nil);
```

Comment: what are you putting inside those strings, can you provide an example?

Comment: Sure. Inside the file `"HKRoutineTitle" = "HK Routine";` and what I see in the title of the page is `HKRoutineTitle`.

Comment: try HKRoutineTitle = "HK Routine"; with no double quotation.

Comment: No way.. That's a string, since when you can put a string without quotes?

Comment: are you adding NSLocalizedString in your ViewController.m inside viewDidLoad method?

Comment: Thanks for helping man, please check my question.. I've edited it.

Comment: I did a sample app and tested the localization on iPhone 6+ device and didn't face any issue. I have shared the URL: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wpdz7vyv154f23m/AAAksI2SxMMLcmaAFEybYn-wa?dl=0 . so is the localization working on simulator and not device? any specific device not working or all of them?